# RBAC (Role Based Access Control) ER Diagram

Tags: database-design, relational-database, cardinality, entity-relationship

I am trying to design an application with **Role Based Access Control**. And I have also designed the ER Diagram. [image: RBAC ERD] So here I try to achieve that a **USER** will have a single **ROLE** and based on the particular **ROLE** it will get permissions for **RESOURCES** set in the **resource_role** table.

Please suggest if I am making any mistake.

As while searching on the internet for the **RBAC ER diagram** I have come across some designs like [image: ERD in Doubt].

Source:- [GitHub Link](https://github.com/talk2amareswaran/simple-rbac-database) and [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZz_eY1Gag8)

In this ER diagram, I have some questions which are as follows:-

1. How a USER can hold multiple **ROLE** as there is no relation between the three i.e **USER**, **ROLE**, and **RESOURCE**. How to identify which **ROLE** to use for the particular user?
2. And how the **user_role** bridge table linked to **role** in **one and only one relation**? As **USER** can have many **ROLE** attached to it.

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that it must be necessary to "identify which role to use" for the user, but (1) it isn't absolutely necessary and (2) that (which role am I going to play) can be a piece of information that the user is required to enter during logon and then stored in his session context.

It isn't absolutely necessary because the semantics behind the resource_role table might be like "access to resource RES requires that the user has role ROLE".  And then granting the access is just a matter of searching whether the user indeed has the required role, and there is no concept of "which role is that user now playing".

Answer (score 0):

You can give try below

[image: RBAC ERD]

it is ongoing part of boilerplate platform below

[Nodejs_Postgresql_VanillaJS_Fastify](https://github.com/matt212/Nodejs_Postgresql_VanillaJS_Fastify)

with case scenarios
[image]